# Cat behavior change: less playful indoors after became more active outdoors and ignoring the other cat

Tags: cats, behavior

I adopted Korian 2 years ago. He was said to be indoors by the shelter place. However I noticed he seemed always curious about the outside at times begging me to open the door for him. I decided to give it a try. I trained him for many months and got him used to go on walks with me on a leash. He enjoyed it a lot.

After some time, I got him a gps and decided to let him go off by himself since there are no real roads around here and mainly forest and open walking areas. To my surprise he was more playful and enjoyed more when I went with him. Alone he never really went to far, but with me walking on his side without the leash, we explored everything together.

After 1 year I adopted Cherry which is definitely not an outdoor cat so she only plays inside.She also needs the company of other cats as it was told me by the shelter and I could confirm that myself. In the first months of the 2 together Korian was more playful with her, running around and chasing her, but that was during winter when he didn't go out as it is too cold for cats where I live. Now during summer months when he has been quite active outdoors, I noticed he never ever plays with her sometimes totally ignoring her presence. I understand he is probably tired from all the walks, and home is a place to sleep/eat . But it's not just that, sometimes he is hanging out with me inside, or just sitting by my side while I work. I know he's very attached to me, but it feels to me that outside is just so much more interesting now that the indoors playground feels boring to him?! Can this kinda of thing happen with cats, like we humans get so entertained by technology nowadays that we lost the taste for more simple stuff (maybe a far-fetched analogy but you got my point :D )?

It kinda breaks my heart that he never goes to spend time with her anymore as she's crazy about him.

I try to build mazes and pillow/cushion castles for them (she loves going inside things and hiding. Before he used to engage in those with her. Now she does it alone and it doesn't last long. I worry that she might be feeling lonely and sad.

Is there any way I can get him to engage more with her? Decreasing outdoors time for him could help? Or might just make him sad instead? Or maybe wait to see how next winter goes since he won't be able to go out anyway...
I was also thinking on adopting a 3rd cat that is only indoors like her, but that's a more complicated solution to the problem (if this is a problem at all...maybe she doesn't care at all)

TLDR;

My cat Korian used to play with Cherry a lot before he became a more active outdoors cat. Now he barely interacts with her and I'm afraid she feels lonely. Can I get him to engage with her again? Should I try getting a 3rd cat that is indoors only , so then all of them are happy?

Comment: Are Korian and Cherry got neutered? If they are, when exactly? Neutering changes the behaviour of the cats and the changes you attribute to some other factors might be related to neutering.

Comment: yes they are both neutered. I don't think it's related to that as they were neutered by the shelter itself long before I even got them

Comment: If they both were neutered before they met each other, you are right, it can't have anything to do with your situation.

Comment: I would at least consider a 3rd cat, we have two litter mates that grew somewhat distant when they were about a year old, but adding our 3rd cat to the group completely turned the dynamic around. She is very social and likes playfighting and chasing with our boy a lot, which leaves our big girl her time to hunt in her outdoor enclosure without being disturbed all the time. Once the constant need to interact was gone, she did start to enjoy it a lot more again.

Answer (score 0):

My daughter has 3 cats and she built a cat pen with a fenced on roof outside her window so all the cats can go out and in and be safe. It resulted in an attitude adjustment for all three cats. They are happy and have stopped acting depressed and isolating.

Answer (score 0):

He may just be tiring himself outside and have less energy for playing when he gets home. Or he may be slowing down a bit as he ages. Unless you see stronger indications of a problem, I wouldn't worry about it.